# querying activerecord models for plain arrays (iterations,map,whatever...needing to learn some things)

Tags: ruby

So, I needed to get some values from associations on my a model:

```
  def provide_list(x,y)
    self.send(x.to_sym).map {|k,v| k[y] }
  end
```

Ok, fine. In that model I can take an instance and do

```
instance.provide_list('resources', 'thefieldiwant')
```

to be more specific, I'll get an array of the values for the associated resource e.g

```
 accountinstance.provide_list('users', 'numberlogins')
 accountinstance.provide_list('users', 'loginproblems')
```

and get arrays like

```
 [45,56,78,1,2,etc]
 [5,5,7,1,2,etc]
```

and then zip them together, getting tuple arrays ([45,5],[56,6],...) for each user I can pass around and whatnot

I want to improve this, so I don't have to run each time manually when I want a specific array of fields for an association (and as a prelude to doing a method that can get and zip what I need with one call for each association instance):

```
  def provide_listing(dd,*args)
    args.each do |ee|
      self.send(dd.to_sym).map {|k,v| k[ee] }
    end
  end
```

This doesn't work, I just get an array of the args, so something I don't know about is tripping this up. Basic question: how do I get the second to behave in tune with the first, except provide an array for each arg.

Open to suggestions about a better way, what I'm doing wrong, if this has been asked before etc. This seems a basic thing that I can't do right this minute, so I'm asking before putting it away for a while so someone with more expertise can enlighten me.

The solution is me learning more refined methods of manipulating ActiveRecord which I'm hardly expert, reviewing this is helping:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem with the second approach is that you are returning the value of #each, which is always just the object #each was called on, in this case args.

I like Pedro's solution, but i'd tweak it slightly:

```
def provide_list(association, *args)
  self.send(association).select(args).map { |r| r.attributes.values }
end
```

Few things to note:

- you don't need to use .to_sym, send and select will take strings or symbols.
- i'd avoid using raw sql, sure it will be faster, but more prone to errors, portability issues and sql injection - never write raw sql unless you have a very good reason.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using a symbol for send now...intially I was getting errors but specifying :myassociation as an argument works without to_sym.

Comment: This more what I was angling toward but did not know originally.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but should work:

```
def provide_list association, *args
  association = self.send(association.to_sym)
  association.connection.select_all("select #{args.join(',')} from #{association.table_name}'").map(&:values)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the console:

```
self.send(dd.to_sym)
```

returns an array of hashes. For example:

```
@arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}]
```

You probably want to return a 2d array like this:

```
def provide_listing( *args )
  args.map do |arg|
    @arr.map do |h|
      h[arg]
    end
  end
end
```

provide_listing( :a, :b, :c )

=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

Comment: After posting my question I did something like this but reversed. This works.